# php - Transfer constants between url include files

Tags: php

I have index.php

```
define ('SERVER_ROOT', '/foo');
define ('SITE_ROOT', 'http://localhost');
include (SITE_ROOT . SERVER_ROOT . '/config.php');
```

in the config.php

```
echo SITE_ROOT;
```

returns null.

---

The reason is that if you include http:// localhost and not just localhost, constants are not passed. But i can't set SITE_ROOT as localhost.. nothing will happen

What's the proper systematical solution to this issue?

Comment: Is your config getting included in the index.php correctly? some configurations do not allow URL includes..

Comment: allow_url_include is set to On in php.ini so yes

Comment: Why you do this with url and not directly?

Comment: I've followed this tutorial to set up proper MVC engine http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/mvc-framework-in-1-hour-part-one

Comment: Yeah, but there was never a url include. Change SERVER_ROOT to the full path on the filesystem and remove SITE_ROOT from include.